# Make button unclickable not just for runtime in android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

How to make a button unclickable for a longtime, not just in when the app is open.

i've tried this, but it works only when the app is still open :

```
    day1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Day01.class);

                  day1.setEnabled(false);


                startActivity(i);

            myVib.vibrate(50);
        }
    });
```

thanks.

Comment: save the last state of the button..like a boolean true or false..and on app start from anywhere just use that boolean

Answer (score 0):

Store the status of the button in `SharedPreference` and in `onCreate` check and disable button if needed.

Please look in to this for understnding `SharedPreference`

[using shared preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: please check the given link